# Understanding inductor behaviour in a diode circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, inductor

I am trying to understand how this circuit works without burning or exploding.

When the inductor current starts to decrease, it acts in a way to increase it and if there is no path, then we see sparks or burning.

In the circuit below instead of DC, imagine we have a sinusoidal voltage source. The diode shuts off at some point when the inductor tries to push current into it and I am troubled to see how the circuit really works. Does the inductor keep the voltage across it if there is no path for discharge like a capacitor?

[image]

Comment: Assuming that the initial condition of the inductor is that its current is zero, and assuming that your diode is an ideal one (not a non-linear one) that holds a fixed voltage drop across it regardless of current through it, then don't you see that initially all of the voltage drop is across the inductor, giving the highest V(L)/L=dI/dt point at t=0+, but that as (I) increases R then drops more voltage gradually lowering V(L) and therefore lowering dI/dt while (I) still continues to increase over time? dI/dt doesn't change sign. It just gets smaller and smaller.

Comment: >> Does the inductor keep the voltage across it if there is no path for discharge like a capacitor?   No.   Soon as the current source goes away (you open the switch), the energy stored in the field around the inductor will try to escape.  It does this by sending the voltage across that inductor up to (theoretically) infinity.  Of course, before it hits infinity, the air will breakdown and there will be a big spark across it as the field collapses.  This is how a car spark-plug works.  It creates 5kV or so to make a spark from just a 12V battery.

Comment: > I am troubled to see how the circuit really works.< When the switch is open ... or closed?

Comment: OnurTR, if you haven't already been sufficiently helped and want to see something else, you will need to say something here. Are you here? Have you read what's been written? Do you still have a question?

Comment: @jonk , I am sorry that I could not reply sir. Inductors confuse me as I am having trouble when or in what situations their magnetic storage field collapses and they create scary amount of voltages across them. I believe in the circuit above, this is not the case and shutting off of the diode does not disturb the inductor or cause it to accumulate scary amount of voltages across it. I am learning about power electronics and the subject has a lot of inductors and diodes which I have problem how they act exactly when I look at circuits. Can you be more explanatory and step by step, I thank you

Comment: @jonk, or in this circuit the current through the inductor does not drop abruptly and it hits 0 amps when diode shuts off, maybe that is why inductor does not cause problem, the problem is I believe when let's say 1 amp current goes through inductor and it is taken forcefully to 0 in an instant quickly, then there will be scary amount of voltage development in the inductor. Is it true sir? However, it is also interrupted (the current) by the diode even though the current hits 0 in the inductor (assuming ideal diode). So much confusion sir, pls help

Comment: @OnurTR There isn't a place in your example where the current suddenly changes. And, in fact, in general it never can suddenly change. (At least, not with the standard simplified inductor model equation of \$V=L\cdot \frac{\text{d}\,I}{\text{d}t}\$.) Where do you see some kind of sudden interruption in your example circuit?

Comment: @jonk when the current goes negative. It is when the diode shuts off. this sudden shutting off, does not it cause the inductor to blow. I mean there are flyback diodes for inductors to discharge. Why in this circuit there is no need for some flyback

Comment: @OnurTR If the diode is a non-linear (realistic) diode, then things get more complex. The voltage it drops will gradually increase as the current increases (not linearly so, though.) But I read your schematic as suggesting an 'ideal' diode in the sense that there is a fixed drop. If so, then all that happens is that the fixed drop subtracts from the voltage source, leaving a smaller applied voltage across the resistor/inductor series pair. I think you are taking things from different circumstances and imagining them here, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of "similar" circuits showing what happens.
I used a switch to show behavior under random switching.

Voltages: one can see the "overvoltages" (very high) at switching OFF.

[image]

Currents

[image]

And here is, what should be done, using a "protection" circuit (for example VDR and/or R serial C).
Overvoltage now limited as ~ 600 V. Varistor is B32K275.
Be aware that scales are not the same as above.

[image]

[image]